# Sql query: How to use right outer join correctly

Tags: sql, sql-server, left-join, right-join

I have to tables: Register and Price.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Register](
[RegisterID] [int] NULL,
[GroupID] [int] NULL,
[TestID] [int] NULL)

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Price](
[ID] [int] NULL,
[GroupID] [int] NULL,
[Price] [bigint] NULL,
[Status] [bit] NULL)
```

[image: Data in tables]

> **Assuming information similar to the image above, consider the following query**

```
SELECT        Price.*
FROM            Register RIGHT OUTER JOIN Price ON Register.GroupID = Price.GroupID
WHERE        (Price.Status = 1) AND (Register.TestID = 50)
```

> **The output will be displayed as shown below.**

[image]

**My expectation is that the first and second rows of the price table will be displayed. So where is my mistake and how should I change the query to get the right output?**

Comment: I typically never user `right join` as I find it hard to follow. I always use a `left join`

Comment: Please in code questions give a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code, including smallest representative example input as code; desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. Give the least code you can that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. (Debugging fundamental.) For SQL that includes DBMS & DDL (including constraints & indexes) & input as code formatted as a table. [ask] Pause work on the overall goal, chop code to the 1st expression not giving what you expect & say what you expect & why.

Answer (score 2):

The restriction on the `Register` table which currently appears in the `WHERE` clause would have to be moved to the `ON` clause to get the behavior you want:

```
SELECT p.*
FROM Register r
RIGHT JOIN Price p ON r.GroupID = p.GroupID AND r.TestID = 50;
WHERE p.Status = 1
```

Note that more typically you would express the above via a *left* join:

```
SELECT p.*
FROM Price p
LEFT JOIN Register r ON r.GroupID = p.GroupID AND r.TestID = 50
WHERE p.Status = 1;
```

Comment: @RashidBagheri . . . I want to emphasize Tim's advice to use `LEFT JOIN` instead of `RIGHT JOIN`.

Comment: @GordonLinoff But some cultures read right to left - so right join can make as much sense as left join does to those that read left to right.

Comment: @Smor . . . That's nice.  SQL is left-to-right so `A JOIN B JOIN C` is parsed as `(A JOIN B) JOIN C`.  Although left-to-right reading is more intuitive for left-to-right alphabets, the ways that the clause is parsed is probably the more important (even if quite subtle) consideration.

Comment: @Tim-Biegeleisen Unfortunately, this query gives the same result as before and shows duplicate records. Is there another solution? (see: https://imgur.com/e1AXGRY or https://img.techpowerup.org/200725/1.png)